# Optimized JPA Query to Flush the column value to 0

Tags: mysql, spring, performance, hibernate, jpa

I have a unique requirement where i need to flush the data of one of the column in database and set the value as 0 using optimized JPA query.

Answer (score 0):

If you have more than a few hundred rows in the table, you need to redesign the schema.

Otherwise,

```
UPDATE tbl SET col = 0;
```

(Sorry, I don't know the JPA equivalent.)